# Preflight CORS issue on serverless AWS Lamba fucntions.

Tags: node.js, cors, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have tried as [official documentation for CORS fix by serverless](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#enabling-cors) & different solutions, but the issue still persists.

What i have done so far is,

1, Set CORS true on all functions.

```
 events:
  - http:
      path: /api/v1/user/login
      method: post
      cors: true
```

2, Set authorizer fix for CORS.

```
 GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
  Properties:
    ResponseParameters:
      gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
      gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
      gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'*'"
    ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
    RestApiId:
      Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
```

3, In response header, i have set as,

```
headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            }
```

**Still am getting issue based on CORS**

```
Error message:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at ’https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v1/user/login' from origin ‘http://localhost:4200’ has
been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: it seems correct. Sometimes, CORS error will be return when your backend return `internal server error`. By the way, are you missing to add `OPTIONS` in that `access-control-allow` fields?

Comment: In your frontend JavaScript code, remove whatever part you added that’s setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin as a request header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is the best or right way to fix this. **But this worked.**

I changed default cors value into custom values.

```
events:
- http:
  path: /api/v1/user/login
  method: post
  cors: true
```

to this,

```
events:
  - http:
      path: /api/v1/user/login
      method: post
      cors:
        origin: '*'
        headers:
          - Content-Type
          - X-Amz-Date
          - Authorization
          - X-Api-Key
          - X-Amz-Security-Token
          - X-Amz-User-Agent
          - Access-Control-Allow-Origin 
          - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
          - Access-Control-Allow-Methods
          - Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        allowCredentials: true
        cacheControl: 'max-age=600, s-maxage=600, proxy-revalidate'
```

and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` doesn't accept wildcards.

If you can not set header values exactly, just remove `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` setting.